# How can I return in spring rest controller Concrete class using parent class?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I have a class A and two clases B and C that are concret classes of A

```
class A {
    private int id;
    //get/set
}

class B extends A { 
    private String attributeB;
    //get/set
}

class C extends A {
    private String attributeC;
    //get/set
}

class AService {
    @Autowired  
    ADao aDao; 
    public List<A> list() {
        return aDao.list();
    }
}
class RestController {
    @Autowired
    AService aService;

    @RequestMapping("api/a")
    public List<A> list() {
        return aService.list(); //Return a List<A> with A, B and C objects
    }
}
```

When I use the api (http request to "/api/a") the Json looks like

```
[
    { id: 1},
    { id: 2},
    { id: 3},
]
```

But the second and third are B and C objects, the response should be

```
[
    { id: 1},
    { id: 2, attributeB: "B"},
    { id: 3, attributeC: "C"},
]
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It will include if serialized to json, provided A, B, C includes setter / getter of there attributes

Comment: I call with angular the api in RestController but it's returning just the A attributes even if the object is a B or C object

Comment: @HemantPatel I edited the question, I forgot to write I have getters/setters methods.

Comment: append method doesn't exists

Comment: I edited the question again, sorry I was thinking in python.

Comment: This is not a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

It works for me

**Controller**

```
// mind the annotation here
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping("api/a")
    public List<A> list() {
        List<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>();
        listA.add(new A());
        listA.add(new B());
        listA.add(new C());
        return listA;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 0,
    "attributeB": null
  },
  {
    "id": 0,
    "attributeC": null
  }
]
```

Jackson library should be present on classpath for serialization / deserialization.
To avoid any dependncy issues, download a sample project from https://start.spring.io/, add web dependencies and generate project.

Comment: This isn't so much an answer as a demonstration that the question is bad.

Comment: I remember that OP already post this initially. But the serialization does not work for him. So it seems to be a library issue.

Comment: I'm using com.fasterxml.jackson.core version 2.6.4
 ->jackson-core
 ->jackson-databind

Answer (score 0):

I tried an example from https://start.spring.io like @Hemant told and it works, unfortunately in my project I'm not using spring-boot so I solved using

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "name")
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = A.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B.class) })
class A {}

class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
```

and now It's working.

Thanks to all of you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not entirely clear, so I guess you are trying to retrieve a response body that should retrun the list of objects. I.e.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/getObjectList")
@ResponseBody
public List<ClassA> getObjectList() {
    List<ClassA> testList = new ArrayList<>();
    testList.add(new ClassA());
    testList.add(new ClassB());
    testList.add(new ClassC());
    return testList;
}
```

Some of these objects happen to extend the base class, classA:

Class A:

```
public class ClassA {

    private String propertyA;

    public ClassA() {
        this.propertyA = "A";
    }

    //get/set
}
```

Class B:
    public class ClassB extends ClassA {

```
    private String propertyB;

    public ClassB() {
        this.propertyB = "B";
    }

    //get/set
}
```

Class C:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class ClassC extends ClassA {

    private String propertyC;

    public ClassC() {
        this.propertyC = "C";
    }

    //get/set
}
```

So far, so good, this code SHOULD generate the following json when you test it on your local environment via GET method:

http://localhost:port/myApp/api/getObjectList

```
[
  {"propertyA":"A"},
  {"propertyA":"A","propertyB":"B"},
  {"propertyA":"A","propertyC":"C"}
]
```

You said that you happen to be using **jackson parser v2.6+**, so If you are using jackson parser, it might have been the case that you **excluded** the serialization of NULL properties.

In the example above, I initialized all properties within the default constructor! However, if you removed the initialized variables and tried to return null field, it wouldn't return NULL values for ClassC object property because the mapper is set to ignore the NULL values.

However, my take is you would have noticed this already and it's more likely that you or someone else might have set the **global ignore** for NULL values in some other place.

In case if you weren't the one using it and if someone else "played a bit" on the same project, you might wish to get involved with [**ignoring NULL fields**](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields)